# Group and sum and fetch with condition in Linq

Tags: linq, c#-4.0

Have a object collection like below

```
UtilityName ="tank1";
Period ="A";
Value=170

UtilityName ="tank1";
Period ="B";
Value=120


UtilityName ="tank2";
Period ="A";
Value=220


UtilityName ="tank2";
Period ="B";
Value=260

UtilityName ="tank3";
Period ="A";
Value=0

UtilityName ="tank3";
Period ="B";
Value=0

UtilityName ="tank4";
Period ="A";
Value=10

UtilityName ="tank4";
Period ="B";
Value=0
```

Need a Linq query where i can group objects by UtilityName and sum by "Value" property
 and get only those objects whose summation is greater then Zero. 
In the above example, i need collection which includes all object except/ excluding Tank 3 object whose summation of Value is 0;

Answer (score 1):

You can try this:

```
var qry = from obj in list
          group obj by obj.UtilityName into g
          where g.Sum(x => x.Value) > 0
          select new { UtilityName = g.Key, Value = g.Sum(x => x.Value)};
```

Answer (score 0):

Something like this:

```cs
var result = objects
    .GroupBy(
        o => o.UtilityName,
        o => o,
        (name, grouping) => new
                            {
                                Sum = grouping.Sum(o => o.Value),
                                Items = grouping
                            })
    .Where(a => a.Sum > 0)
    .SelectMany(a => a.Items);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can just remove the values with a zero first (if all elements with same UtilityName has a 0 value, they won't be present in the groups).

If you don't have negative values, this will be the easiest way.

But if you need a count, for example, this won't work anymore.

```
var result = list.Where(m => m.Value > 0)
                 .GroupBy(m => m.UtilityName)
                 .Select(m => new {
                   UtilityName = m.Key,
                   SumValues = m.Sum(x => x.Value)
                 });
```

Less "fragile" :

```
   var result = list
                   .GroupBy(m => m.UtilityName)
                   .Select(m => new {
                      UtilityName = m.Key,
                      SumValue = m.Sum(x => x.Value)
                   })
                   .Where(m => m.SumValue > 0);
```

**EDIT**

Not clear if you want, as result, a new object with the sum, or if the sum is just a way to exclude some objects...

Answer (score 0):

```
list.GroupBy(x => x.UtilityName)
    .Where(x => x.Sum(y => y.Value) > 0)
    .SelectMany(g => g);
```